# IE 11 disable="True" not working

Tags: html, css, yui

Can anyone help me in knowing why `disable="true"` for a button doesn't work in Internet Explorer 11 whereas `disable="disable"` works? Also provide a solution which works both in IE 9 and IE 11.

Comment: "disable" != "disabled" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct and easy way to disable buttons is by adding `disabled` attribute:

```html
<button>I am not disabled!</button>
<br /><br />
<input type="button" value="Disabled input" disabled/>
<button disabled>I am disabled!</button>
```